# Adding EventListener to an array, getting TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, function, for-loop

I'm using for to addEventListeners to all of the buttons. When I do so I get the message "value is not a function". What needs to be done?

```
var buttons:Array;
buttons = new Array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","Æ","Ø","Å");

for (var i:int = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
{
    buttons[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onKeyPress);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use getChildByName("name") to get the reference to the object, if the values insde the array is name of element.

Try this,

```
var buttons:Array;
buttons = new Array("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z","Æ","Ø","Å");

for (var i:int = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) 
{
    this.getChildByName(buttons[i]).addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onKeyPress);
}
```

In this case I have used **this** by considering that the elements are attached on current container.

Answer (score 0):

`buttons[i]` is not an interactive object, it is a String. You cannot add an event listener to primitive types.

You have to use either references or instance names. If "A", "B", ... are your instance names, then you have to provide the full/relative path, e.g.: `root.myClip[buttons[i]].addEventListener`...

Comment: How can I in the most effective way add an event listener to the whole array?

Comment: Like you are doing. But you have to have something referenceable in your array. It is just an array of strings what you have there => buttons[i] returns a string.

Comment: @user3040958 use a for() loop